# PDO SELECT query not displaying any results

Tags: php, html, database, pdo

I am attempting to learn `PDO` and I am following a tutorial and for some reason I can't get anything to display within my table. I have one record within my database that should be displaying. I am not receiving any errors, so I am completely unsure of what it could be.

Does anyone see what it could be?

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $name = '';
    $user = '';
    $password = '';

    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $password);

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

}
?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Save</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php
        $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="id" value="<?$row['id'];?>"></td>
                <td><input name="first" value="<?$row['first'];?>"></td>
                <td><input name="last" value="<?$row['last'];?>"></td>
                <td><input name="product" value="<?$row['product'];?>"></td>
                <td><button name="save" type="submit">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: you forgot the `echo`

Comment: or you can do something like this... `<?=$row['id'];?>` since you are using shorthand...

Comment: The video is not using `echo` in it, so how would his show, but not mine?

Comment: `<?= $row` or `<?php echo $row` - Edit: didn't see that first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short code is `<?=` and not `<?` Also you need to be sure that short codes are turned on in PHP

It is safer to use the long `<?php` like so, as this will work on any configuration of PHP

```
<td><input name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"></td>
```

Comment: I know `prepared statements` are the most safe and secure way to communicate with the `database`, how could I do my `SELECT` query in a `prepared statement` with `PDO`?

Comment: For this query you dont actually need to, as it is only going to be executed once and there are no parameters being used from unsafe places like $_POST or $_GET

Comment: Gotcha! So, I only need to do prepared statements from things like forms and other instances that use the `$_POST` and `$_GET` methods?

Comment: Yes, basically. Or if you are going to execute a query in a loop for example. Then you prepare it outside the loop and execute it normally with parameter binding inside the loop. That way you benefit from ONE compilation/Optimization phase in the database, rather than repeated compilation/optimization phases that would happen when running a `$dbc->query()` style query with repeated `'$val'` concatenations inside a loop, as well as Injection protection

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!